# local variables outside a function in python

Tags: python, function, variables, global, local

i have a code that goes like this

```
def inputs():
    q_number = int(1)
    number_of_q = int(0)
    q = {}
    x = {}
    y = {}
    xxxx = 1
    for i in range(4):
        C = float(qq[xxxx].get())
        X = float(xxx[xxxx].get())
        Y = float(yy[xxxx].get())
        if C != 0 or C != "":
            q[q_number] = C
            x[q_number] = X
            y[q_number] = Y
            q_number += 1
            number_of_q += 1
```

it works fine the only problem i have is i am trying to print the duples q , x , y outside of the function so i can use them in other stuff but it just wont work

i have tried to write the functiona as normal and global the duple q x y outside of the function

```
def inputs():
    q_number = int(1)
    number_of_q = int(0)
    q = {}
    x = {}
    y = {}
    xxxx = 1
    for i in range(4):
        C = float(qq[xxxx].get())
        X = float(xxx[xxxx].get())
        Y = float(yy[xxxx].get())
        if C != 0 or C != "":
            q[q_number] = C
            x[q_number] = X
            y[q_number] = Y
            q_number += 1
            number_of_q += 1
    global number_of_q, q_number, q, x, y
    print(number_of_q, q_number, q, x, y)
```

but the program gives me an error ( NameError: name 'number_of_q' is not defined )
can someone help me out ?

Comment: Why not just make those values function parameters, and the make the function return the updated values as a tuple? Using globals are almost never the way to update values, you call a function with the inputs it needs, it generates output, then you (through your code) decide what to do with the result, which might including "updating the variables that you passed in".

Comment: Please update your question with your real code. It seems to me that there should be an error with: `qq[xxxx].get()`. What is `qq`?

Comment: What is the intention for `if C != 0 or C != ""` ? Which values will not meet the condition? Also `int(1)`  etc is superfluous as 1 in already an int.

Comment: I cant because a tkinter program is inputting these values through multiple entry boxes, 12 values to be exact and the function is being called by a button that has its command set as the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below creates groups of StringVar. The `update_fltdb` function mirrors the StringVar groups to `fltdb` as float values.  I fleshed it out with the 12 Entry widgets, and the Button.

```
import tkinter as tk

root  = tk.Tk()

SVDB  = ([], [], []) #groups of StringVar
fltdb = ([], [], []) #groups of float


#mirror SVDB as float results
def update_fltdb() -> None:
    fltdb = ([], [], [])
    for group, out in zip(SVDB, fltdb):
        for sv in group:
            try   : out.append(float(sv.get()))
            except: 
                sv.set('0.0')
                out.append(0.0)
    
    print(fltdb)
    

#build stringvar database
for x, group in enumerate(SVDB):
    for y in range(4):
        (sv := tk.StringVar(root)).set(f'{x}.{y}')
        tk.Entry(root, textvariable=sv).grid(column=x, row=y, sticky='nswe')
        group.append(sv)


#button
button = tk.Button(root, text='click', command=update_fltdb)
button.grid(column=x, row=y+1, sticky='e')
button.invoke() #update_fltdb


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root.mainloop()
```

You can unpack to any name(s) you need.

```py
q, x, y    = fltdb
qv, xv, yv = SVDB
```